# Android bypassing theme setting

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-theme, android-styles

I have a Layout with a TextView in an application - not written by me. I want to set it to bold or change the font family in the xml. In the application written by me it works correctly. But in this one, the change doesn't show. I suppose that's because a theme was applied. If I change the setting programmatically it works and if I set it to bold programmatically it works.

> myTextView.Typeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD).

How can I overwrite the theme setting?

UPDATE:
The Layout that i have is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lFiltro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tUno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/archivo_black"
        android:shadowColor="#33b5e5"
        android:shadowDx="4"
        android:shadowDy="4"
        android:shadowRadius="5"


        android:text="This is my text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `app:theme` attribute in the `TextView`?

Comment: I don't the in my layout the attribute "app:theme"

Comment: It should be available if you start typing "theme" in the `TextView` element. Are you using a custom font?

Comment: I want use a custom font but it don't change

Comment: Custom fonts don't always allow for bold typeface.

Comment: I have tried to change font for this. The font family that i have tried to set allow bold.

Comment: Try removing anything but base theme in `styles.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
```

to your **TextView** xml and change what is after ***TextAppearance.*** according to the suggestions you will get.